# How to select dropdown item (select option) in google closure?

Tags: javascript, google-closure, google-closure-library

on jQuery i could just do $('#idOfSelectTag').val('someValue');

How to do the same in google closure?

Answer (score 4):

The closest equivalent would be:

```
goog.dom.forms.setValue(
    goog.dom.getElement('idOfSelectTag'), 'someValue');
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Derek Slager from closure mailing list. The correct way :

```
goog.dom.forms.setValue(goog.dom.getElement('idOfSelectTag'),'someValue');
```